# How do i use 4 buttons for debouncing in arduino sheild if i can only use 2 ISR i.e. INT0 and INT1

Tags: c, embedded

There are 4 buttons which need to take input , To prevent debouncing i need to use ISR (interrupt service routine ) . INT0 and INT1 interrupt vector can handle switch 1 and 2 , but we need to take care of the rest 2 switches to prevent debouncing , How should i do it ?

Comment: What is the mcu? Are there port interrupts? I mean: you have to give us more infos about your system ...

Comment: It's atmega 328p , I mean we can use int0 and int1 for the 2 buttons , but for the other 2 we have to think of another way to do debouncing

Comment: Looking at [the man](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_datasheet.pdf) the mcu have Pin Change Interrupts. So based on your schematic, you can use the correct interrupt to the job.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using pin interrupts to debounce is to use a periodic timer interrupt (or system tick, if you have one). With this method, you have virtually unlimited debounce capability.

With your hardware configured to generate a tick interrupt every 5-20 milliseconds, you can sample the pins each time. Your debounce period will be determined by the tick period and the number of samples you collect. For each button, you can store each sample as a bit in a byte, halfword, or word, depending on how many samples are used.

For example, a simple debounce could use a 10 millisecond tick and only two samples. On each interrupt you would have something similar to:

```
const byte mask = 0x3;                    // this mask has N lsb's set,
                                          // where N is the number of samples.
static bit debounced = 0;                 // this stores the debounced output of a button
static byte samples = 0;                  // this stores the raw samples
samples = samples << 1;                   // shift the samples to make room
samples |= ReadBit(theThingToDebounce);   // for the new sample (and or it in)
if ((samples & mask) == 0x0)              // test that all samples are 0
{
    debounced = 0;                        // debounced output is 0
}
else if ((samples & mask) == mask)        // test that all samples are 1
{
    debounced = 1;                        // debounced output is 1
}
```

This can be simplified a bit depending on your requirements, or made more complicated. If you need to signal your application on debounced button state change, you'll need to do additional checks to see if the previous state was the opposite of the new state, and then signal. If you don't need to do that, then you can actually evaluate the samples (to decide if you have a debounced 1 or 0) on each call to check the state of the button.

The above snipped can pretty easily be turned into real code. The number of samples can be changed easily with the type of `mask`and `samples`, and the value of `mask`. Changing the period would be the configuration of your tick period, which is going to be much more device specific.

Generally, `mask` could be defined based on `N` samples rather than updating it manually. If you want the `N` least significant bits of a number set, you can accomplish that, but calculating `2^N-1`, or much easier in code: `(1<<N) - 1`. This gives us a new definition of:

```
const byte nSamples = 4;
const byte mask = (1 << nSamples) - 1; // 1 << 4 = 0x10, 0x10 - 1 = 0xF.
                                       // This gives us a number with the four LSB's set.
```

To run this on more than one pin, you simply need to make `samples` and `debounced` an array sized based on the number of pins to monitor, and then perform the algorithm in a loop for each pin.